# Is it acceptable to just go ahead and wipe a tag which obviously shouldn't be used and has few questions tagged?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

I can see a lot of tag burninate requests being posted here. Is it acceptable to just go ahead and wipe a tag which obviously shouldn't be used and has few questions tagged?

I'm curious because I was already doing it and one of the reviewers commented with:

> It isn't a good approach to bump up an old thread (and off-topic) just to retag it. Instead, you can suggest a tag synonym or start a new meta thread.

Also, is it ok to re-tag a question which is obviously off-topic and should be closed? If it will be closed the question which had answers will remain with a tag and won't get removed from the system... or am I mistaken?

Comment: I saw this question in the Community Bulletin, and really wanted to answer "no, dumbass; they're _requests_!" Then I read the question and found out that you meant something else. Awww.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Same Here.  I updated the title to clarify the author's intent.

Comment: @KyleMit Good job

Comment: Can you make always 100% totally sure that the community would agree with you that it is a good idea, and that you didn't overlook a specific meaning that nicely refines another tag?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It depends on the exact situation. How many questions have the tag? Why is it a bad tag? Are there replacement tags? Do you have sufficient privileges to take all the required actions? Etc. In the very general case I'd say, fall back on the community for advice and consensus. If anything to have a single post that others can refer to who think "hey, where has this tag gone and why?". And there's nothing wrong with a quick sanity check of your own point of view.

That said, with enough experience and enough of a grasp of what makes a good tag and what makes a tag bad, you could go and delete a tag which is only used on one or two questions (a handful at most) without bothering the community. There are several users out there which do so on a daily basis and who do a commendable job. But that does take experience. And even they get it wrong from time to time and are called out for it on occasion.

**If you don't feel comfortable about it, ask. You won't bother the community with it, we're here to help.**

For a tag to disappear, no (non-deleted) questions have to be tagged with it any more. If a question is merely closed, the tag will hang around if it's not removed.

Comment: As an example I can give this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617864/htmlayout-tutorials-or-guides/623363#623363 tagged with `terrainformatica` which is just company name and the tag is definetly useless but I couldn't remove it because my edit failed. And it failed probably because this question should be closed. Also I wasn't able to produce a suitable tag i.e. `HTMLayout` or `Sciter` (because they don't exist) which are products of terrainformatica. (Also I believe the gui tag is irrelevant but I can't leave quesiton without tags)

Comment: BTW it had only 4 questions tagged so it's not a problem to do it manually :) but unfortunately I wasn't able to remove the last one.

Comment: If all of those questions referred to a specific product of that company it might perhaps have been worth it to tag it with an appropriate product tag.

Comment: Yeah it was the case and that's what I did (it either had been tagged already or I suggested appropriate product tag), but for this particular question mentioned products don't have a tag at all and I am unable to create new tag.

Comment: In such a case it's not bad to call upon the community and those who do have sufficient privileges to take the actions that are required.

Comment: But I didn't want to bother anyone because that question should be closed (I think) and just wanted to get rid off `terrainformatica` tag or you don't agree with me?

Comment: [terraininformatica] is not great, true. But removing it leaves the question with [gui] only. Or [as you suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5065335) [user-interface]. That doesn't give it a whole lot to go on either. I haven't gone through your other edits, but perhaps a retag to something specific for their HTMLLayout product would have been appropriate. Even I am not certain (it's not my domain either) so I personally might have asked for input. But that's me.

Comment: Actually I didn't suggest user-interface I just left with gui tag ( (even though I believe it's incorrect as well as I said above), no idea how it appeared there.

Comment: Ah, those are synonyms, so apparently your edit triggered the display of the main-tag. Not your doing. :)

Comment: Also this edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5065666 got declined, I agree that it's minimal but I have nothing else to edit in question itself and just want to get rid off tag. I even mentioned that this question should be closed. What should I do differently? Or just stop killing tags? :S Also should I post everything from comments to the question itself..?

Comment: Using suggested edits to just remove bad tags from bad questions is probably not a great plan, yes. Since nothing you can do will improve the question to the point that it actually belongs on the site, you should pretty much expect those to be rejected as too minor.